# How do I make a build profile reference modules that are within a "black box" library layer?

Tags: dojo, dojo-build

The tutorials got me going with the Dojo build system. However I'm left with a question that'll make or break the possibility of deploying a fully built release in my case. It is possible that the tutorial explains it, but that I didn't get it. Apologies if that was the case !

I use a library that lives inside an AMD layer ; let's call it `blackboxLayer.js`. There are several packages inside that layer, but I suppose the question would be the same if there was only one. So let's say that `blackboxLayer.js` contains a single package called `blackbox`, with modules `blackbox/A` and `blackbox/B`. To be sure that things are fun, that layer is bootable. And of course it's closed source stuff.

My app modules reference `blackbox/A` or `blackbox/B`. How do I make my build profile go look for the `blackbox` package inside that `blackboxLayer.js` file, rather than in a directory ?

Thanks for any input. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interim solution I've been using since this question has been posted is NOT to use dojo's builder... Instead I use a lightweight grunt pattern that concatenates AMD sources into a layer, and then I reference the layer from dojoConfig's `deps` property. The concatenation process is visible here : https://github.com/gruntjs-updater/grunt-amd-concat

Answer (score 1):

If built file blackboxLayer.js is in relative path `/release/blackbox/layers`, there is a separate dojo layer

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path to dojoLayer.js"></script>
```

and

```
var dojoConfig = {
    packages: [
        { name: 'blackbox', location: 'release/blackbox' }
    ]
};
```

then code inside this function can reference modules A and B,

```
require(['blackbox/layers/blackboxLayer'],
function () {
    require(['dojo/parser', 'dojo/ready'],
    function (parser, ready) {
        ready(function () {
            require(['blackbox/A', 'blackbox/B'],
            function (blackboxA, blackboxB) {

                // call blackboxA and blackboxB

            });
        });
    });
});
```

If there is no separate dojo layer, you can reference blackboxLayer.js in the script tag, and omit the package def and requiring blackboxLayer.

Comment: Hello. It would be akward to have the function code depend on the build, wouldn't it ?